# Как при обращении к файлу с одним именем отдать файл с другим?

Tags: nginx

Требуется настроить правила в *nginx* так, чтобы при обращении к файлам с именами:

```
name_S.jpg
name_L.jpg
name_XL.jpg
```

отдавался файл с именем:

```
name_XXL.jpg?
```

Имена файлов отличаются только окончанием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в секцию `server` следующее правило:

```
rewrite ^(/static/img/.*)_(S|L|XL)\.jpg$ $1_XXL.jpg last;
```

где `/static/img/` -- путь к вашим изображениям.

Подробнее почитать можно [тут](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).